# How can I filter a list of the users which are being returned by lookup on the custom Visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lookup

I can show an input field with lookup to select a user by using the following code snippets:

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!usr.ManagerId}"/>
```

and Apex (controller constructor):

```
usr = new User();
```

But, I don't want to show all users there, I want to filter them based or their profiles and/or roles. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to build a custom lookup feature. The standard lookup window shows all active users.